# facing issue in google Xpath creation using Parent child relationship

Tags: automated-testing

My self created Xpath is below

```
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class= 'RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/div/input")).sendKeys("Kedarnath review");
```

after executing the above code in scripts I am facing a below error:-

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@class= 'RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/div/input"}

  (Session info: chrome=71.0.3578.98)

  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b544917107a59d4153d4bf78e1b90),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds

For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:25:48'

System info: host: 'DESKTOP-R0GNJAC', ip: '192.168.0.4', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_151'

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, acceptSslCerts: false, applicationCacheEnabled: false, browserConnectionEnabled: false, browserName: chrome, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 2.44.609538 (b655c5a60b0b54..., userDataDir: C:\Users\ASHUTO~1\AppData\L...}, cssSelectorsEnabled: true, databaseEnabled: false, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:58969}, handlesAlerts: true, hasTouchScreen: false, javascriptEnabled: true, locationContextEnabled: true, mobileEmulationEnabled: false, nativeEvents: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, takesHeapSnapshot: true, takesScreenshot: true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour: ignore, unhandledPromptBehavior: ignore, version: 71.0.3578.98, webStorageEnabled: true}

Session ID: 457a1320a6927a7db9e699565755b811

*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//div[@class= 'RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/div/input}

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)

at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)

at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)

at google.main(google.java:13)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this XPATH `//div[@class= 'RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/div/input`, I had the same issue.

If you notice the `div` before input is closed by `</div>` in Elements like 
`<div class="pR49Ae gsfi" jsname="vdLsw"></div>`

So try this instead as below. Because input exists in `div[2]`:

`"//div[@class= 'RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/div/input`

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This error means that your xpath is incorrect and WebDriver cannot find the element:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: 
no such element: Unable to locate element: ...
```

Assuming that you look for the search bar, you can identify the element by name attribute:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='q']").sendKeys("Kedarnath review");
```

As a side note, don't use xpath if you have other options. Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27355003/advise-on-hierarchy-for-element-locators-in-selenium-webdriver) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to use "sendkeys" to the search textbox I would use XPATH that uses the "title" rather than specifically from the absolute. NOTE: Google changes a lot of their front end to prevent people from using automation software, just beware that these front end elements can change often. Try the below instance for XPATH:

```
//input[@title='Search'].sendKeys("Kedarnath review");
```

Answer (score 1):

`/div` before `/input` is closed.

So use

```
("div[@class=`RNNXgb']/div/div[2]/input")
```

This worked for me.